# How to get the information of the currently logged in user in jira data center/server plugin module

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I’m creating a Custom field module in my plugin, and I want to control the visibility of that field based on " Which groups are the user is a member of " of the logged user.

**My question is:** how would I be able to retrieve the groups that the user is a member of?

Note: I’m using the `JiraAuthenticationContext` to get the information about the currently logged-in user and I have the ID, name, username, and email of the user but nothing is about the role and the user membership of this user.